# Android Animation - View Not Refreshing

Tags: android, animation

This is probably a pretty simple question, I have a fragment that is added dynamically. The fragment has a button with a click event that animates the view +50 on the x-axis and +50 on the y-axis.

The animation works fine but the problem is when I click on the button after the animation it doesn't work but the click event remains in the original location. If that doesn't make sense I will post a link to the youtube video that shows what is going on. I am just curious if there is something I need to refresh?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLaS6u5v4m0

Here is my code :

```
public class AnimationFragment extends Fragment {
    public AnimationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    View view;
    float curX, curY, newX, newY;
    boolean animating = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        curX = 0; curY = 0;
        view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animation, container, false);
        // get the button and add the onclick event
        Button animateButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.animateButton);
        //
        if (null != animateButton) {
            animateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    animateButtonClick(v);
                }
            });
        }
        return view;

    }


    public void animateButtonClick(View view)  {
        // wait for the animation to be complete
        if (animating) return;
        animating = true;

        // get the new x and new y
        newX = curX + 50.0f;
        newY = curY + 50.0f;
        // get the layout that will be animated
        final RelativeLayout animationFragment = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.animationFragment);
        Animation slide =  new TranslateAnimation(
                                        Animation.ABSOLUTE,curX,
                                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, newX,
                                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, curY,
                                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, newY);
        // add other animation attributes
        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        // start the animation
        animationFragment.startAnimation(slide);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // make the view enable
                animating = false;
                // sets the new x and new y
                curX = newX;
                curY = newY;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without:

```
slide.setFillAfter(true);
slide.setFillEnabled(true);
```

From the documentation, setFillEnabled

> If fillEnabled is true, the animation will apply the value of
>   fillBefore

setFillAfter

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed
>   will persist when it is finished.

Try first without, if it works and you want it to happen before, remove both `setFillAfter() / setFillEnabled()` methods. If you want it to happen after, use only `setFillAfter(true)`

Comment: When I got rid of those events the animation would not work unless I set the view animationFragments x and y in the onAnimationEnd event. Which makes sense because it is not animating the view but a bitmap of the view. But the weird part was it still looks like garbage. 

`animationFragment.setX(newX);
 animationFragment.setY(newY);
`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI9zWDiA_zA

Comment: You've marked the question as solved but your previous comment says it is not - I'm confused. Take a look at the parameters of TranslateAnimation, it seems like you are using it wrong: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html